Constrained optimization with complex variables
I'm new to Mathematica so I'm sorry if my request will be stupid. I would like to find the minimum of the function $(|\alpha||\beta|-|\gamma||\delta|)^2$ with the constraints $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 + |\gamma|^2 + |\delta|^2 = 1$ and $|\gamma|^2 + |\delta|^2 - 2|\gamma||\delta|\cos{(Arg{\delta})} = 1 +\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a parameter s.t. $0 \leq \epsilon \leq 1$.
To do that I tried the following:
Minimize[{(Abs[\[Alpha]] Abs[\[Beta]] - 
 Abs[\[Gamma]] Abs[\[Delta]])^2, Abs[\[Alpha]]^2 + Abs[\[Beta]]^2 + Abs[\[Gamma]]^2 + 
 Abs[\[Delta]]^2 == 1 && Abs[\[Gamma]]^2 + Abs[\[Delta]]^2 - 
 2 Abs[\[Gamma]] Abs[\[Delta]] Cos[Arg[\[Delta]]] == 
1 + \[Epsilon] &&  0 <= \[Epsilon] <= 1 }, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta]}]

but my notebook runs endlessly. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Replace the constraint
$$
-2 | \gamma |  | \delta |  \cos (\arg (\delta ))+| \gamma | ^2+| \delta | ^2=\epsilon +1\land 0\leq \epsilon \leq 1
$$
with the equivalent constraint
$$
1\leq -2 | \gamma |  | \delta |  \cos (\arg (\delta ))+| \gamma | ^2+| \delta | ^2\leq 2
$$
{valMin, argMin} = 
 Minimize[{(Abs[α] Abs[β] - 
      Abs[γ] Abs[δ])^2, 
   Abs[α]^2 + Abs[β]^2 + Abs[γ]^2 + 
     Abs[δ]^2 == 1, 
   1 <= Abs[γ]^2 + Abs[δ]^2 - 
     2 Abs[γ] Abs[δ] Cos[Arg[δ]] <= 
    2}, {α, β, γ, δ}]




{0, {α -> 0, β -> 0, γ -> -1, δ -> 0}}

And ϵ is just 1 minus the last constraint
1-(Abs[γ]^2 + Abs[δ]^2 - 
  2 Abs[γ] Abs[δ] Cos[Arg[δ]] /. argMin)


0


Alternatively you can specify epsilon as a minimization variable:
Minimize[{(Abs[α] Abs[β] - 
     Abs[γ] Abs[δ])^2, 
  Abs[α]^2 + Abs[β]^2 + Abs[γ]^2 + 
     Abs[δ]^2 == 1 && 
   Abs[γ]^2 + Abs[δ]^2 - 
     2 Abs[γ] Abs[δ] Cos[Arg[δ]] == 
    1 + ϵ && 
   0 <= ϵ <= 
    1}, {α, β, γ, δ, ϵ}]


{0, {α -> 0, β -> 0, γ -> 1, δ ->  0, ϵ -> 0}} 


Also note that if you don't want a solution with a bunch of zeros, removing the lower bound of the last constraint produces a solution that still meets all the constraints, with all the variables being non-zero in value:
{valMin, argMin} = 
 Minimize[{(Abs[α] Abs[β] - 
       Abs[γ] Abs[δ])^2, 
    Abs[α]^2 + Abs[β]^2 + Abs[γ]^2 + 
       Abs[δ]^2 == 1 && 
     Abs[γ]^2 + Abs[δ]^2 - 
       2 Abs[γ] Abs[δ] Cos[Arg[δ]] <= 
      2}, {α, β, γ, δ}] // ToRadicals


{0, {α -> 1/16 Sqrt[1/2 (143 - Sqrt[7905])], β ->  1/16 Sqrt[1/2 (143 + Sqrt[7905])], γ -> -(7/ 16), δ -> -(1/2)}} 

ϵVal = 
 1 - (Abs[γ]^2 + Abs[δ]^2 - 
     2 Abs[γ] Abs[δ] Cos[Arg[δ]] /. argMin)



31/256


Thanks a lot for your answer! There is however a problem: I know that the function has its minimum when epsilon = 0 (numerically I expect the minimum to be epsilon^2/4) but  I would like to have a solution in terms of epsilon (considered as a fixed given parameter). It seems computationally demanding so maybe I'll just check numerically the cases I'm interested in.
